# Adding a information column into stack bar in R graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojtZy.jpg)I want to add an information column on the right side of the stack bar area (see [the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbGJG.jpg)). Like **Do at all** combines **Often** and **Occasionally**. I want to do this in R.

## Create the data frame

```
# Load required libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Create the data frame
data <- data.frame(
  event = c("Talking with family", "Donating good", "Posting on social media", "Give interview", "Working/Voluntering for a charity", "Speaking with journalist", "Participating in protest"),
  lk1 = c(23, 20, 21, 40, 36, 40, 23),
  lk2 = c(10, 36, 30, 12, 12, 12, 25),
  lk3 = c(36, 20, 37, 36, 40, 36, 40),
  lk4 = c(31, 24, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12),
  lk1_lk2 = c(33, 56, 51, 52, 48, 52, 48)
)

# Reshape the data for ggplot
data_long <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(lk1:lk4), names_to = "likert", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(event = factor(event, levels = rev(unique(event))))
```

## Plotting

```
ggplot(data_long, aes(x = value, y = event, fill = likert)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), color = "white", size = 3) +
  geom_text(data = data_long %>% filter(likert == "lk1"), 
            aes(label = lk1_lk2, x = max(value) + 2, y = event),
            hjust = -50, color = "black", size = 3) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(), expand = expand_scale(add = c(1, 10))) + # Adjusting x-axis limits
  labs(title = "Preference Distribution for Various Events",
       x = "Percentage",
       y = "Event") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  geom_text(data = NULL, aes(x = Inf, y = Inf, label = "Do at All"),
            hjust = 1, vjust = 1, color = "black") +  # Add text at right-top corner
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("lk1" = "Often", "lk2" = "Occasionally", "lk3" = "Never", "lk4" = "Prefer not to say"))
```

Comment: I attached it , thanks

Comment: The step making your data long, i.e. `data` -> `data_long` is missing.

Comment: add for this data_long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to make separate plots, then combine using cowplot:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

p_main <- ggplot(data_long, aes(x = value, y = event, fill = likert)) +
  geom_col() + # note geom_col() is the same as geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  geom_text(aes(label = value), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), color = "white", size = 3) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = \(x) paste0(x, "%"), expand = expansion(add = c(1, 1))) + 
  labs(x = "Percentage", y = "Event") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("lk1" = "Often", "lk2" = "Occasionally", "lk3" = "Never", "lk4" = "Prefer not to say"))

p_do_at_all <- ggplot(
    distinct(data_long, event, lk1_lk2), 
    aes("", event)
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = lk1_lk2), size = 3) +
  theme_void()

# I would think you could use get_legend() here, 
# but it throws an error due to trying to get multiple components.
# as a workaround:
legend <- get_plot_component(p_main, "guide-box", return_all = TRUE)[[4]]

p_main <- p_main + scale_fill_discrete(guide = "none")

title <- ggdraw() +
  draw_label("Preference Distribution for Various Events")

lab_do_at_all <- ggdraw() +
  draw_label("Do at all", size = 10)

plot_grid(
  title, 
  plot_grid(legend, lab_do_at_all, rel_widths = c(8, 1)),
  plot_grid(p_main, p_do_at_all, align = "h", rel_widths = c(8, 1)),
  ncol = 1,
  rel_heights = c(3, 2, 30)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use `stat_summary` to add the "information column" and to compute the values on the fly. More advanced part is the use of `stage` to position the labels *after* computing the sum of `value`. To add the `"Do at all"` label I use a secondary axis. Finally I positioned the legend manually to align it with the `"Do at all"` label (Note: I'm using the new API for inside legends introduced with `ggplot2 3.5.0`).

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data_long, aes(x = value, y = event, fill = likert)) +
  geom_col(
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5, reverse = TRUE),
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5, reverse = TRUE),
    color = "white", size = 3
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    geom = "text",
    data = data_long %>% filter(likert %in% c("lk1", "lk2")),
    fun = sum,
    aes(
      label = after_stat(x),
      x = stage(value, after_stat = 125),
      group = event
    ),
    color = "black", size = 3
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 100, 25),
    labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1),
    expand = expand_scale(add = c(1, 10)),
    sec.axis = dup_axis(
      breaks = 125,
      labels = "Do at all\n(Often or Occasionally)",
      name = NULL
    )
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Preference Distribution for Various Events",
    x = "Percentage",
    y = "Event",
    fill = NULL
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "inside",
    legend.position.inside = c(0, 1.075),
    legend.justification = c(0, 1),
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    plot.margin = margin(5.5, 30, 5.5, 5.5)
  ) +
  scale_fill_discrete(
    labels = c(
      "lk1" = "Often", "lk2" = "Occasionally",
      "lk3" = "Never", "lk4" = "Prefer not to say"
    )
  )

ggsave("foo.png",
  width = 750, height = 600, units = "px",
  scale = 3, bg = "white"
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, That is also a useful alternative way

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the position and texts that you want to show in the `data`. Like this:

```
# Load required libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Create the data frame
data <- data.frame(
  event = c("Talking with family", "Donating good", "Posting on social media", "Give interview", "Working/Voluntering for a charity", "Speaking with journalist", "Participating in protest"),
  lk1 = c(23, 20, 21, 40, 36, 40, 23),
  lk2 = c(10, 36, 30, 12, 12, 12, 25),
  lk3 = c(36, 20, 37, 36, 40, 36, 40),
  lk4 = c(31, 24, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12),
  lk1_lk2 = c(33, 56, 51, 52, 48, 52, 48)
)

# Reshape the data for ggplot
data_long <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(lk1:lk4), names_to = "likert", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(event = factor(event, levels = rev(unique(event))))


# add labels
data$labels = letters[1:7]
# add the position to show labels
# don't need y, it is just the 'event'
data$x = 110
data


ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = data_long, aes(x = value, y = event, fill = likert),stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(data = data_long, aes(x = value, y = event,label = value), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), color = "white", size = 3) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(), 
                     breaks = seq(0, 100, 20), # limits the labels to show
                     expand = expansion(add = c(1, 15))) + # Adjusting x-axis limits
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("lk1" = "Often", "lk2" = "Occasionally", "lk3" = "Never", "lk4" = "Prefer not to say")) +
  geom_text(data = NULL, aes(x = Inf, y = Inf, label = "Do at All"),
            hjust = 1, vjust = 1, color = "black") +
  geom_text(data = data, aes(x = x, y = event, label = labels),
            hjust = 1, vjust = 1, color = "black")
```

Comment: when I run these codes, and it is not the same layout what  I want in the attached image.